# Почему после "то есть" не ставится запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Почитала обсуждение вопроса о лишних запятых. В одном из ответов автор привел пример того, что многие ставят запятую после "то есть", хотя она там не нужна.
Признаться честно, я как раз из тех, кто ставит.))) А почему вообще она там не ставится? Ведь это, по-моему, самое что ни на есть вводное слово. И, кстати, это же всегда интересовало по поводу слова "однако" в начале предложения. Оно ведь даже интонационно отделяется от предложения, так почему же тут не нужна запятая?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Уважаемая Карин! Ваши сомнения понятны, а объясняются упрощенным пониманием того, что есть вводное слово. Ведь это не только слово, которое выделяется паузой. Вводное слово должно выражать уверенность, неуверенность, чувство и т.д. Слово же "то есть" - это союз, который начинает собой пояснительную конструкцию и может быть заменен союзом "или" (В зоопарке жил бегемот, или (то есть) гиппопотам). Понятно, что союзы не выделяются запятыми. 
Что касается союза "однако", то он дейстительно не выделяется запятыми в начале предложения, так как выполняет функцию именно союза, который можно заменить союзом "но" (Я просил его о помощи, однако он ничего не сделал). Когда же слово "однако" стоит в середине или в конце предложения, то выполняет роль вводного слова, выражая некое чувство (Я просил его о помощи, он, однако, ничего не сделал). Не знаю, насколько понятны мои пояснения, однако я старался сделать их убедительными

Comment: >> Слово же "то есть" - это союз, который начинает собой пояснительную конструкцию и может быть заменен союзом "или" (В зоопарке жил бегемот, или (то есть) гиппопотам).

Далеко не всегда союз. *То есть как?* *То есть ты уедешь, а я останусь?* И т.д. и т.п.
В последнем предложении "то есть" ~ "значит", причём именно в значении вводного слова.

Comment: То есть как? - очень смутно вырисовывается функция этих слов. Не кажется ли Вам, что это похоже на частицу, тем более, что можно заменить частицей "именно"? Так же и выражении "То есть ты уедешь..."

Comment: Да, первая фраза чисто разговорная, к ней и вопросов нет.
А вот ко второй – есть. В ней "то есть" – практически полный синоним "значит". *Значит, ты уедешь, а я останусь?*

Comment: "То есть" бывает: 1) союзом; 2) частицей (употребляется для усиления эмоциональности высказывания, а также (в сочетании с «как») в ответной реплике для выражения недоумения, удивления, осуждения. "То есть как это не поедешь?"); 3) разговорным вводным словом - паразитом (очень редко: "Там, знаете, то есть, буквально нет ни единого человечка". "Передай вот это самое письмишко в самые, то есть, его ручки"). "То есть ты уедешь, а я останусь?" - союз, значение "другими словами".

Comment: Ага, так вот почему в последнем случае "другими словами" (или "значит") является вводным, а "то есть" - вводным не является?

Comment: Только союз ЗНАЧИТ, сближаясь по значению с вводным словом, всегда выделяется запятой (и то это пока вопрос спорный). Не надо путать значения союзов и вводные слова. Слово ОДНАКО вводное в значении ТЕМ НЕ МЕНЕЕ, но это не значит, что ТЕМ НЕ МЕНЕЕ тоже надо выделять запятыми. Это одна из самых больших трудностей изучения вводных слов, от которой в голове каша.

Comment: Слов, которые употребляются только как вводные и всегда обособляются, очень мало (например, во-первых, по-моему и некоторые др.). Вводность сама по себе всего лишь функция, которую могут выполнять все части речи. Обнаружить логику в этом вопросе трудновато, поэтому  вводные слова нужно проверять по справочникам.

Answer (score 0):

В другом значении, то есть - частица, а не вводное слово.

Answer (score 0):

Не стану принципиально спорить с самим общепринятым правилом - не ставить запятую после "то есть". Раз уже общепринято, то обязательно к исполнению на письме.
Но несколько иной взгляд на это все же выскажу. "То", не меняя смысла выражения, мы легко можем заменить на  "это"; "то" и "это" - местоимения. А "есть" является глаголом. Местоимение, употребленное в качестве подлежащего вместе с глаголом-сказуемым образуют предложение: это есть (то есть). И значит употребление на письме "то есть" представляет собой оборот речи, который выражается сложным предложением. Сначала "то есть" (это есть), а далее следует пояснительная часть (конкретизирующая смысл первого) - другое предложение уже со своим сушествительным и подлежащим. Например: "То есть(,) он был первым парнем на деревне". Возможно, если не ошибаюсь, такую грамматическую форму (То есть, ......[подлежащее и сказуемое]) следует считать сложно-подчиненным предложением и тогда запятая после "то есть" вполне логична.