# Запятая при словах "ну", "то есть"

Tags: пунктуация

У меня возникли трудности в расстановке запятых в следующем случае (выделен жирным шрифтом):

> В том подъезде не валялось ничего.
>   **Ну то есть совсем ничего.**

Подскажите, где нужно ставить запятые, и нужен ли в предложении дефис? Я видел несколько вариантов расстановки и поэтому запутался окончательно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Не нужны знаки препинания**: В том подъезде не валялось ничего. **Ну то есть** совсем ничего.

Ну ― частица, ТО ЕСТЬ ― пояснительный союз. Иногда НУ можно обособить как междометие, если делается пауза в устной речи.

Примеры

Два выстрела прозвучали одновременно. **Ну то есть** ― почти одновременно… [Вера Белоусова. Второй выстрел (2000)]

**Ну, то есть** я не хотел сказать, что прежде было хуже ― напротив. [Татьяна Соломатина. Акушер-ХА! Байки (2009)]

Comment: А как узнать, делается пауза или нет?! И *какой длины* эта пауза – тянет на запятую? Вот если бы на ноль целых пять сотых секунды длиннее, то да, а так нет... А вдруг один паузу сделает, а другой нет? "А я так вижу!" – и что с ним поделаешь... Пунктуация рухнула, да?

Comment: Про длину пауз у Лопатина спросите, про все "вдруг и если", вот он удивится такому нездоровому интересу к его предмету. Или хотя бы вот это почитайте, если лично не знакомы:  "Имеющие усилительное значение частицы, в отличие от междометий, не отделяются знаками от слов, при которых они стоят: — Ну пойди, пойди сюда (Плат.); — Ну надо же! — всё изумлялась Марья (Шукш.); 
Усилительные частицы не имеют ударения, они СЛИВАЮТСЯ со следующими словами, тогда как междометия всегда ударны и потому они отделены от следующих слов ПАУЗОЙ". http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=130#pp130

Answer (score 2):

Не дефис, а тире.

В подобных чисто разговорных оборотах ставьте, как хотите. С одним исключением: *то есть* не обособляется. То есть в вашем случае после *то есть* запятая не ставится.

Answer (score 1):

**ТО ЕСТЬ, *союз и частица***
**1. Союз.** Присоединяет слова или предложения, поясняющие или уточняющие высказанную мысль; то же, что «а именно, другими словами».
 ***После союза «то есть» запятая не ставится:***

*В этой книге рассказывается о сказочной стране, в которой жили малыши и малышки, **то есть** крошечные мальчики и девочки, или, как их иначе называли, коротышки.*
 Н. Носов, Незнайка в Солнечном городе.

**2. Частица.** Употребляется для усиления эмоциональности высказывания, а также (в сочетании с «как») в ответной реплике для выражения недоумения, удивления, осуждения.
 ***Не требует постановки знаков препинания*:**

*«Вывозили? **То есть** как вывозили?» – спросила Регина Петровна, вдруг побледнев.*
 А. Приставкин, Ночевала тучка золотая.
[**ТО ЕСТЬ**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_733)

**В Вашем предложении - *по правилам* - никаких запятых или тире не нужно.**

Можно сравнить с очень похожими примерами:
 *Вот мир Ефремова практически однозначно - космоопера, и высшего уровня... **Ну то есть** с этим мало кто спорит...*
[**Стругацкие и космоопера**](http://wap.gramota.forum24.ru/?1-3-20-00000384-000-0-0-1320654725)
*Новый роман признанных мастеров детектива Анны и Сергея Литвиновых - не совсем детектив. **Ну то есть** в нем есть все: и захватывающий сюжет, и преступления, и похищение, и погони, и тайна.*
[**Книжная полка**](http://kp.ua/life/565094-knyzhnaia-polka-v-proze-tolko-devushky)
*Солдаты охраняют. **Ну, то есть** точно я не знаю, но в проходных солдаты стоят.*
[**Т.Устинова, Гений пустого места**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=5hs-PsAg5cEC&pg=PT172&lpg=PT172&dq=%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D1%83%20%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C&source=bl&ots=l9sBYmPXC1&sig=9QFpNjfn1iB_ibCDoU_Swi8fy74&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvp6GEsZLUAhXJCpoKHW82C4c4ChDoAQgrMAI#v=onepage&q=%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D1%83%20%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C&f=false)

Еще на нашем же сайте было разъяснение:
[**Почему после “то есть” не ставится запятая?**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/39548/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F)